# Normalization between three correlated columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to get best practices from the start. I'm trying to normalize a database about college sports teams and I can't figure out how to to the N2 step because colleges can have the same sports/mascots. For instance, I have 4 teams shown in the image.[image]

I can't sort my second table by school, because one school could have multiple sports, I can't sort by sport, because one sport can have multiple schools. If I had two elements (football + OU), I could figure out the third, but how should I arrange it so that all attributes are dependent on one key?

Comment: Why did you stop at two tables?  Schools could have one or many mascots and a mascot belongs to one or many schools (or do they?).  Each school can have zero or many sports each sport belongs to zero to many schools.  It's the association of a school to a sport that results in a mascot and an email.  So do you need a school, sport, mascott and schoolSportMascot table? maybe not mascott just because they have same name "pete" doesn't mean they are the same outfit and are the same mascott...

Comment: While colleges may have the same "mascot" they are not truly the same.  the look and feel is different even if they share names. but I can see the same mascot being used by different sports at the same school, or a multiple mascots existing at one school for different sports.  Example: the HUSKY is used by many schools; but it's not the same presentation of a husky at each school.  so the entity Husky (mascot) is different or has different properties. though they are all Huskies...

Answer (score 0):

By inspection, your school table on the bottom right could be normalized so that redundant information is removed.  It could be refactored into the following two tables:

**school_sports**

```
school         | sport
Oklahoma State | Baseball
Oklahoma State | Football
Oklahoma       | Football
Alabama        | Football
```

**school_mascots**

```
school (PK)    | mascot
Oklahoma State | Pete
Oklahoma       | Boomer
Alabama        | Big Al
```

In the mascot table, now the mascot name depends only on the primary key school name.  In the sports table, the primary key is the combination of school and sport.  But these two combined entries should be unique in that table.

Comment: Excellent! I don't know why I didn't think of that, but that'll work perfectly!

Comment: sport is also part of the PK of the first table.

Comment: @rd_nielsen I see it, give me a minute.

Comment: I agree in concept; though in reality I think teams have mascots; which means a school could have multiple mascots.

Comment: @xQbert You're right, but the sample data imply otherwise.  Actually, colleges do seem to have a primary single mascot.

Comment: @xQbert See here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistol_Pete_(Oklahoma_State_University)

Comment: In this case, schools are allowed to have different mascots depending on the sport, like some schools have a female mascot for women's soccer. That complicates things.... :/

Comment: oh I agree that given the data this makes sense.  from a requirement standpoint I would want to make sure I understand the carnality between mascot and school and mascot and sport.

Comment: @RobinClower Then your question does not reflect the actual problem.

Comment: @RobinClower  Yep which is why I would have 3 entities.  School, Mascot, Sport and the association of school, mascot and sport would contain the email address.  As some schools have 1 mascot for multiple sports, while others have different mascots for different sports:  Some schools even "Reuse" mascots at different schools; thus the reason to have a Mascot table. as it can reused in the school for different sports, or even by different schools (though usually with different presentation though they may share name, colors, etc)

Comment: Sorry Tim, I didn't think of that scenario until you and xQbert brought it up and there are some schools where that's the case.

Comment: So xQbert, you're saying I should have the email be the primary key for a school table, for a sport table, and for a mascot table? That makes sense to me.